# where to put my loop in order to get result

Tags: python

why my code below doesn't run, although I have defined R, it tells me I didn't?

```
N= 2

def f(R):
    for i in range(N):
        R = i
    return 2*R

print f(R)
```

Comment: Where did you define `R` and/or `N` here? What is the exact traceback?

Comment: Why do you need `f` to take `R` as an argument if you just assign it to something different and change it over and over.  You could just return `2 * (N-1)` and get the same result

Comment: What is your f(R) supposed to do?

Comment: Unless `N <= 0`, the `R` parameters has no sense at all, since it will be overwritten by `R = i`.

Comment: my actual code is very complicated , so I try to put some simple variables to see where is the problem. my question is I am defining R as values 0 and 1 (don't I?),  so why python still doesn't recognize it?

Comment: In your example, you have not defined R, which obviously causes the code not to run.  Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us to help you.

Comment: sorry asking lots of questions but the loop lines is not a definition for R?

Comment: f(R) suppose to give me two numbers.

Comment: You are passing `R` as an argument to `f`, you cannot define `R` in `f`

Comment: also I don't understand why if take the loop out and try the code it works?

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

`R` in your function definition will take the value you pass in to it. But you pass in `R`, that doesn't exist in that scope. Try to pass something constant

```
print f(10)
```

or define R before the call

```
R = 10
print f(R)
```

Note that I could have named this variable `C` or `anything`, that value is passed in and in the `f` function is called `R`, but it's not the same `R`

Comment: I think this answer correctly solves the question the user is asking.  I still have no idea what they want the function to do however.

Comment: I did define R , it gets the numbers 0 and 1, how should I define it?

Comment: We can't see that in your code. You probably have some other logical errors

Comment: @ursus I think you got what I have problem with. So I could name my variable x, b or any thing , then I tell python what to put instead of that variable. why R is not the same. in f(R) is R and then I tell it what is R which is a range..I think I am maybe confused with the logic of it

Comment: if you can help me understand this or suggest me some text to study I would appreciate it.

Comment: Try Introduction to Computer Science and Programming Using Python from MIT on Edx platform.